# finding the limit with theta

Tags: calculus, limits

[image]
So I really don't understand how I am supposed to get the answer to this or where to start. Should I use the quotient rule then am I supposed to plug in 0?? Can someone help me out please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is to apply L'Hopital's Rule. But if you don't know that, here is a simpler way:

First, write the expression as follows: $\dfrac{\cos 7\theta - 1}{\sin 4\theta} = \dfrac{7\theta \cdot \frac{\cos 7\theta - 1}{7\theta}}{4\theta \cdot \frac{\sin 4\theta}{4\theta}} = \dfrac{7}{4} \cdot \dfrac{\frac{\cos 7\theta - 1}{7\theta}}{\frac{\sin 4\theta}{4\theta}}$.

Now, you just need to evaluate $\displaystyle\lim_{\theta \to 0}\frac{\cos 7\theta - 1}{7\theta} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\cos x - 1}{x}$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{\theta \to 0}\frac{\sin 4\theta}{4\theta} = \lim_{y \to 0}\frac{\sin y}{y}$.

Comment: As JimmyK4542 implies, everyone who works with limits should know $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\cos x - 1}{x}$ and $\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{\sin y}{y}$.